# mysterious newline in google apps script string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

can anyone tell me why this string:

var emailBody = "Thank you for submitting your request for an LWS ATP worksheet for the 2017-2018 school year."

Is rendering as:

Thank you for submitting your request for an LWS ATP worksheet for the

2017-2018 school year

Seriously, where is that newline coming from?

Thank you :)

Comment: Rendering in what?  A web page? And how?

Comment: It's rendered that way in Outlook but it's fine in GMail no line break.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fetching the string from the body of any email this kind of problem generally arises. The only way to get rid of the new line character is by using the following expression:

```
emailBody = emailBody.replace(/\n/gi," ");
```

if it still does not work then probably it will work by using "\r" instead of "\n" in the above given expression.

Comment: Is regex REALLY the only want in Google Apps script to replace a newline character with a space or null or dash or something OR is it just the experts favorite?